# UIButton and UILabel unable to be removed from view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have two UIButtons that I added to my view

```
[self.view addSubview:button1];
[self.view addSubview:button2];
```

These buttons have a selector and in the selector is a menu where the user can choose an option and this option can vary in string size for the button so I decided to remove the buttons from the view and reload them again with different string size and button size. I have am getting the information from an API call so there is where I set the buttons up to my view. I tried to do this:

```
[button1 removeFromSuperview];
```

Also tried:

```
[self.button1 removeFromSuperView];
```

Now, for the UILabel I have it inside a table view cell because the string is long and covers my detailTextLabel. I am using UITableViewCellStyleValue1 for the cells. I have tried to use NSLineBreakByWordWrapping and set the numberOfLines to 0 as well as 5 so I then decided to add the UILabel inside the table view cell so I can control how far the string goes and I can also wrap that around. Since the cell was writing over and over the label every time the cell with the table view was hidden, I decided to create the label inside the if(cell == nil) statement.Like the button, this label also gets refreshed when the buttons are pressed and a menu option is chosen so I have to remove it from the view, the same way i did the buttons. For some reason it isn't working. Anyone have any thoughts/ideas/suggestions?

I also NSLog(@"%@",[button1 superview]) after I removed it to make sure that the button was indeed (null) as well as the label, and they do show up on the terminal as null but the buttons overlap each other, in fact you can still click the old button and you can see it underneath the new button. Same goes with the label. If you need any code let me know, this problem is frustrating me so much!

Also, I am on iOS7 and for some reason my device isn't displaying the status bar. I've tried to change it inside the info.plist -> status bar style. I've tried the 3 options it has but none of them seem to work. I checked all my xib files and checked for any hidden keywords in my .m files. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned the button was making an API call I am guessing you may be threading that section of code. If that's the case then the reason its not working is likely because you are not allowed to update the UI in a background thread.

Try replacing:

`[button1 removeFromSuperview];`

with this:

`[button1 performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];`

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure. My next guess would be that you accidentally removed the wrong UIButton for some reason?

Try this: 

`for (int i = [self.view.subviews count] -1; i>=0; i--) {
    if ([[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        [[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];
    }
}`


If removing every UIButton from the subview helps then its likely that you've got an extra UIButton.

Answer (score 1):

I deeply suggest using storyboards, they make working with the UI a lot easier! They also allow you to play with constraints to see how your UI elements react to longer text or to the screen rotating, etc...

That apple tutorial:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html

goes through a simple app with storyboards!

Comment: I know how to use storyboard, well sort of, but for this project I was kind of thrown into it and they're working with nib files so I just thought it would be okay if i kept doing it with nibs. thanks for the suggestion though!